# I'm trying to create a primary key from 2 columns, but it doesn't work well

Tags: sql, database, oracle, foreign-keys, create-table

I'm learning Oracle by myself.

Here's my code:

```
create table Schedule
(
    Schedule_SN number(10) primary key,
    ScreeningDate date not null,
    Price number(6) not null
);
    
create table Seat 
(
    Schedule_SN number(10) REFERENCES Schedule(Schedule_SN),
    Seat_SN varchar2(4) not null
);
    
create table Reservation
(
    Reservation_SN number(15) primary key,
    DCtype number(2) not null,
    DCamount number(7),
    PaymentMethod number(1) not null,
    TotalPrice number(7) not null,
    ReservationDate date not null
);
    
create table Reservation_details    ** I need help here **
(
    Reservation_SN number(15) REFERENCES Reservation(Reservation_SN),
    Schedule_SN number(10) REFERENCES Schedule(Schedule_SN),
    Seat_SN varchar2(10) REFERENCES Seat(Seat_SN),
    CONSTRAINT Reservation_detailesPK primary key (Reservation_SN, Schedule_SN)
);
```

Error messages:

> Errors - ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
> 02270. 00000 -  "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"
> *Cause:  A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary key constraint in the referenced table.
> *Action:   Find the correct column names using the ALL_CONS_COLUMNS catalog view

How can I make my 2 columns `(Reservation_SN, Schedule_SN)` into a primary key?

Comment: Hello Bee, welcome to Stack Overflow. Plese provide your code as text rather than images (we can copy/paste and play around with text, not with images). Also please share the error message that you are getting.

Comment: By the way, when declaring a foreign key as part of the column definition, it will automatically inherit the datatype of the parent if you don't specify it. I would just use `seat_sn references seat(seat_sn)`.

Comment: Thank you William, I'm gonna edit now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `seat_sn`. You want child column in `reservation_details` to reference parent column in `seat`, but the parent column is not a primary or unique key. Actually, `seat` has no primary key; just make `seat_sn` the primay key of this table (if this fits your use case), and the rest should run fine:

```
create table seat (
    schedule_sn nmber(10) references schedule(schedule_sn),
    seat_sn varchar3(4) primary key
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c61826ddf18eec1d3787189d329f7f01)**

Comment: Thank you dude! you are a god for me